# xtable + addcontentsline

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I'd like to add an additional argument to the `xtable` Function. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
library(xtable)
table_raw <- matrix(4, nrow=2, ncol=2)
table1 <- xtable(table_raw, digits=0, caption="Nice table")

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\hline
& 1 & 2 \\ 
\hline
1 & 4 & 4 \\ 
2 & 4 & 4 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Nice table} 
\end{table}
```

Now I'd like to add the argument `\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Title of Table}` that the table looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\hline
& 1 & 2 \\ 
\hline
1 & 4 & 4 \\ 
2 & 4 & 4 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Nice table} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Nice table}
\end{table}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the `xtable:::print.xtable` function.
You can find an `extra` argument to add your string.

```
myprint.xtable <-
  function (x,
            type = getOption("xtable.type", "latex"),
            file = getOption("xtable.file", ""),
            append = getOption("xtable.append",  FALSE),
            floating = getOption("xtable.floating", TRUE),
            floating.environment = getOption("xtable.floating.environment", "table"),
            table.placement = getOption("xtable.table.placement", "ht"),
            caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement",  "bottom"),
            caption.width = getOption("xtable.caption.width",  NULL),
            latex.environments = getOption("xtable.latex.environments", c("center")),
            tabular.environment = getOption("xtable.tabular.environment", "tabular"),
            size = getOption("xtable.size", NULL),
            hline.after = getOption("xtable.hline.after", c(-1, 0, nrow(x))),
            NA.string = getOption("xtable.NA.string", ""),
            include.rownames = getOption("xtable.include.rownames", TRUE),
            include.colnames = getOption("xtable.include.colnames", TRUE),
            only.contents = getOption("xtable.only.contents", FALSE),
            add.to.row = getOption("xtable.add.to.row", NULL),
            sanitize.text.function = getOption("xtable.sanitize.text.function", NULL),
            sanitize.rownames.function = getOption("xtable.sanitize.rownames.function",  sanitize.text.function),
            sanitize.colnames.function = getOption("xtable.sanitize.colnames.function",  sanitize.text.function),
            math.style.negative = getOption("xtable.math.style.negative", FALSE),
            math.style.exponents = getOption("xtable.math.style.exponents",  FALSE),
            html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes", "border=1"),
            print.results = getOption("xtable.print.results", TRUE),
            format.args = getOption("xtable.format.args", NULL),
            rotate.rownames = getOption("xtable.rotate.rownames", FALSE),
            rotate.colnames = getOption("xtable.rotate.colnames", FALSE),
            booktabs = getOption("xtable.booktabs", FALSE),
            scalebox = getOption("xtable.scalebox", NULL),
            width = getOption("xtable.width", NULL),
            comment = getOption("xtable.comment", TRUE),
            timestamp = getOption("xtable.timestamp", date()),
            extra = NULL,
            ...) {
    caption <- attr(x, "caption", exact = TRUE)
    short.caption <- NULL
    if (!is.null(caption) && length(caption) > 1) {
      short.caption <- caption[2]
      caption <- caption[1]
    }
    pos <- 0
    if (include.rownames)
      pos <- 1
    if (any(hline.after < -1) | any(hline.after > nrow(x))) {
      stop("'hline.after' must be inside [-1, ", nrow(x),
           "]")
    }
    if (!is.null(add.to.row)) {
      if (is.list(add.to.row) && length(add.to.row) == 2) {
        if (is.null(names(add.to.row))) {
          names(add.to.row) <- c("pos", "command")
        }
        else if (any(sort(names(add.to.row)) != c("command", "pos"))) {
          stop("the names of the elements of 'add.to.row' must be 'pos' and 'command'")
        }
        if (is.list(add.to.row$pos) &&
            is.vector(add.to.row$command, mode = "character")) {
          if ((npos <-
               length(add.to.row$pos)) != length(add.to.row$command)) {
            stop(
              "the length of 'add.to.row$pos' must be equal to the length of 'add.to.row$command'"
            )
          }
          if (any(unlist(add.to.row$pos) < -1) |
              any(unlist(add.to.row$pos) >  nrow(x))) {
            stop("the values in add.to.row$pos must be inside the interval [-1, ",
                 nrow(x),
                 "]")
          }
        }
        else {
          stop(
            "the first argument ('pos') of 'add.to.row' must be a list, the second argument ('command') must be a vector of mode character"
          )
        }
      }
      else {
        stop("'add.to.row' argument must be a list of length 2")
      }
    }
    else {
      add.to.row <- list(pos = list(),
                         command = vector(length = 0,
                                          mode = "character"))
      npos <- 0
    }
    if (type == "latex") {
      if (!booktabs) {
        PHEADER <- "\\hline\n"
      }
      else {
        if (is.null(hline.after)) {
          PHEADER <- ""
        }
        else {
          hline.after <- sort(hline.after)
          PHEADER <- rep("\\midrule\n", length(hline.after))
          if (hline.after[1] == -1) {
            PHEADER[1] <- "\\toprule\n"
          }
          if (hline.after[length(hline.after)] == nrow(x)) {
            PHEADER[length(hline.after)] <- "\\bottomrule\n"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      PHEADER <- ""
    }
    lastcol <- rep(" ", nrow(x) + 2)
    if (!is.null(hline.after)) {
      if (!booktabs) {
        add.to.row$pos[[npos + 1]] <- hline.after
      }
      else {
        for (i in 1:length(hline.after)) {
          add.to.row$pos[[npos + i]] <- hline.after[i]
        }
      }
      add.to.row$command <- c(add.to.row$command, PHEADER)
    }
    if (length(add.to.row$command) > 0) {
      for (i in 1:length(add.to.row$command)) {
        addpos <- add.to.row$pos[[i]]
        freq <- table(addpos)
        addpos <- unique(addpos)
        for (j in 1:length(addpos)) {
          lastcol[addpos[j] + 2] <- paste(lastcol[addpos[j] +
                                                    2], paste(
                                                      rep(add.to.row$command[i], freq[j]),
                                                      sep = "",
                                                      collapse = ""
                                                    ), sep = " ")
        }
      }
    }
    if (length(type) > 1)
      stop("\"type\" must have length 1")
    type <- tolower(type)
    if (!all(!is.na(match(type, c("latex", "html"))))) {
      stop("\"type\" must be in {\"latex\", \"html\"}")
    }
    if (("margintable" %in% floating.environment) &
        (!is.null(table.placement))) {
      warning("margintable does not allow for table placement; setting table.placement to NULL")
      table.placement <- NULL
    }
    if (!is.null(table.placement) &&
        !all(!is.na(match(
          unlist(strsplit(table.placement,
                          split = "")), c("H", "h", "t",
                                          "b", "p", "!")
        )))) {
      stop(
        "\"table.placement\" must contain only elements of {\"h\",\"t\",\"b\",\"p\",\"!\"}"
      )
    }
    if (!all(!is.na(match(caption.placement, c("bottom",
                                               "top"))))) {
      stop("\"caption.placement\" must be either {\"bottom\",\"top\"}")
    }
    if (type == "latex") {
      BCOMMENT <- "% "
      ECOMMENT <- "\n"
      if (tabular.environment == "longtable" & floating ==
          TRUE) {
        warning("Attempt to use \"longtable\" with floating = TRUE. Changing to FALSE.")
        floating <- FALSE
      }
      if (floating == TRUE) {
        BTABLE <- paste(
          "\\begin{",
          floating.environment,
          "}",
          ifelse(
            !is.null(table.placement),
            paste("[", table.placement, "]",
                  sep = ""),
            ""
          ),
          "\n",
          sep = ""
        )
        if (is.null(latex.environments) ||
            (length(latex.environments) ==
             0)) {
          BENVIRONMENT <- ""
          EENVIRONMENT <- ""
        }
        else {
          BENVIRONMENT <- ""
          EENVIRONMENT <- ""
          if ("center" %in% latex.environments) {
            BENVIRONMENT <- paste(BENVIRONMENT, "\\centering\n",
                                  sep = "")
          }
          for (i in 1:length(latex.environments)) {
            if (latex.environments[i] == "")
              next
            if (latex.environments[i] != "center") {
              BENVIRONMENT <- paste(BENVIRONMENT,
                                    "\\begin{",
                                    latex.environments[i],
                                    "}\n",
                                    sep = "")
              EENVIRONMENT <- paste("\\end{",
                                    latex.environments[i],
                                    "}\n",
                                    EENVIRONMENT,
                                    sep = "")
            }
          }
        }
        ETABLE <- paste("\\end{", floating.environment,
                        "}\n", sep = "")
      }
      else {
        BTABLE <- ""
        ETABLE <- ""
        BENVIRONMENT <- ""
        EENVIRONMENT <- ""
      }
      tmp.index.start <- 1
      if (!include.rownames) {
        while (attr(x, "align", exact = TRUE)[tmp.index.start] ==
               "|")
          tmp.index.start <- tmp.index.start +
            1
        tmp.index.start <- tmp.index.start + 1
      }
      if (is.null(width)) {
        WIDTH <- ""
      }
      else if (is.element(tabular.environment, c("tabular",
                                                 "longtable"))) {
        warning(
          "Ignoring 'width' argument.  The 'tabular' and 'longtable' environments do not support a width specification.  Use another environment such as 'tabular*' or 'tabularx' to specify the width."
        )
        WIDTH <- ""
      }
      else {
        WIDTH <- paste("{", width, "}", sep = "")
      }
      BTABULAR <- paste(
        "\\begin{",
        tabular.environment,
        "}",
        WIDTH,
        "{",
        paste(c(attr(
          x, "align",
          exact = TRUE
        )[tmp.index.start:length(attr(x,
                                      "align", exact = TRUE))], "}\n"),
        sep = "", collapse = ""),
        sep = ""
      )
      if (tabular.environment == "longtable" && caption.placement ==
          "top") {
        if (is.null(short.caption)) {
          BCAPTION <- "\\caption{"
        }
        else {
          BCAPTION <- paste("\\caption[", short.caption,
                            "]{", sep = "")
        }
        ECAPTION <- "} \\\\ \n"
        if ((!is.null(caption)) && (type == "latex")) {
          BTABULAR <- paste(BTABULAR, BCAPTION, caption,
                            ECAPTION, sep = "")
        }
      }
      BTABULAR <- paste(BTABULAR, lastcol[1], sep = "")
      ETABULAR <- paste("\\end{", tabular.environment,
                        "}\n", sep = "")
      if (!is.null(scalebox)) {
        BTABULAR <- paste("\\scalebox{", scalebox,
                          "}{\n", BTABULAR, sep = "")
        ETABULAR <- paste(ETABULAR, "}\n", sep = "")
      }
      if (is.null(size) || !is.character(size)) {
        BSIZE <- ""
        ESIZE <- ""
      }
      else {
        if (length(grep("^\\\\", size)) == 0) {
          size <- paste("\\", size, sep = "")
        }
        BSIZE <- paste("\\begingroup", size, "\n",
                       sep = "")
        ESIZE <- "\\endgroup\n"
      }
      BLABEL <- "\\label{"
      ELABEL <- "}\n"
      if (!is.null(caption.width)) {
        BCAPTION <- paste("\\parbox{", caption.width,
                          "}{", sep = "")
        ECAPTION <- "}"
      }
      else {
        BCAPTION <- NULL
        ECAPTION <- NULL
      }
      if (is.null(short.caption)) {
        BCAPTION <- paste(BCAPTION, "\\caption{", sep = "")
      }
      else {
        BCAPTION <- paste(BCAPTION, "\\caption[", short.caption,
                          "]{", sep = "")
      }
      ECAPTION <- paste(ECAPTION, "} \n", sep = "")
      BROW <- ""
      EROW <- " \\\\ \n"
      BTH <- ""
      ETH <- ""
      STH <- " & "
      BTD1 <- " & "
      BTD2 <- ""
      BTD3 <- ""
      ETD <- ""
    }
    else {
      BCOMMENT <- "<!-- "
      ECOMMENT <- " -->\n"
      BTABLE <- paste("<table ", html.table.attributes,
                      ">\n", sep = "")
      ETABLE <- "</table>\n"
      BENVIRONMENT <- ""
      EENVIRONMENT <- ""
      BTABULAR <- ""
      ETABULAR <- ""
      BSIZE <- ""
      ESIZE <- ""
      BLABEL <- "<a name="
      ELABEL <- "></a>\n"
      BCAPTION <- paste("<caption align=\"", caption.placement,
                        "\"> ", sep = "")
      ECAPTION <- " </caption>\n"
      BROW <- "<tr>"
      EROW <- " </tr>\n"
      BTH <- " <th> "
      ETH <- " </th> "
      STH <- " </th> <th> "
      BTD1 <- " <td align=\""
      align.tmp <- attr(x, "align", exact = TRUE)
      align.tmp <- align.tmp[align.tmp != "|"]
      if (nrow(x) == 0) {
        BTD2 <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = ncol(x) + pos)
      }
      else {
        BTD2 <- matrix(
          align.tmp[(2 - pos):(ncol(x) + 1)],
          nrow = nrow(x),
          ncol = ncol(x) + pos,
          byrow = TRUE
        )
      }
      BTD2[regexpr("^p", BTD2) > 0] <- "left"
      BTD2[BTD2 == "r"] <- "right"
      BTD2[BTD2 == "l"] <- "left"
      BTD2[BTD2 == "c"] <- "center"
      BTD3 <- "\"> "
      ETD <- " </td>"
    }
    result <- xtable:::string("", file = file, append = append)
    info <- R.Version()
    if (comment) {
      result <-
        result + BCOMMENT + type + " table generated in "+info$language + " "+info$major + "."+info$minor + " by xtable "+packageDescription("xtable")$Version +
        " package"+ECOMMENT
      if (!is.null(timestamp)) {
        result <- result + BCOMMENT + timestamp + ECOMMENT
      }
    }
    if (!only.contents) {
      result <- result + BTABLE
      result <- result + BENVIRONMENT
      if (floating == TRUE) {
        if ((!is.null(caption)) && (type == "html" ||
                                    caption.placement == "top")) {
          result <- result + BCAPTION + xtable:::as.string(caption) +
            ECAPTION
        }
        if (!is.null(attr(x, "label", exact = TRUE)) &&
            (type == "latex" && caption.placement ==
             "top")) {
          result <- result + BLABEL + attr(x, "label",
                                           exact = TRUE) + ELABEL
        }
      }
      result <- result + BSIZE
      result <- result + BTABULAR
    }
    if (include.colnames) {
      result <- result + BROW + BTH
      if (include.rownames) {
        result <- result + STH
      }
      if (is.null(sanitize.colnames.function)) {
        CNAMES <- sanitize(names(x), type = type)
      }
      else {
        CNAMES <- sanitize.colnames.function(names(x))
      }
      if (rotate.colnames) {
        CNAMES <- paste("\\begin{sideways}", CNAMES,
                        "\\end{sideways}")
      }
      result <- result + paste(CNAMES, collapse = STH)
      result <- result + ETH + EROW
    }
    cols <- matrix("", nrow = nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x) +
                     pos)
    if (include.rownames) {
      if (is.null(sanitize.rownames.function)) {
        RNAMES <- sanitize(row.names(x), type = type)
      }
      else {
        RNAMES <- sanitize.rownames.function(row.names(x))
      }
      if (rotate.rownames) {
        RNAMES <- paste("\\begin{sideways}", RNAMES,
                        "\\end{sideways}")
      }
      cols[, 1] <- RNAMES
    }
    varying.digits <- is.matrix(attr(x, "digits", exact = TRUE))
    for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
      xcol <- x[, i]
      if (is.factor(xcol))
        xcol <- as.character(xcol)
      if (is.list(xcol))
        xcol <- sapply(xcol, unlist)
      ina <- is.na(xcol)
      is.numeric.column <- is.numeric(xcol)
      if (is.character(xcol)) {
        cols[, i + pos] <- xcol
      }
      else {
        if (is.null(format.args)) {
          format.args <- list()
        }
        if (is.null(format.args$decimal.mark)) {
          format.args$decimal.mark <- options()$OutDec
        }
        if (!varying.digits) {
          curFormatArgs <- c(list(
            x = xcol,
            format = ifelse(
              attr(x,
                   "digits", exact = TRUE)[i + 1] < 0,
              "E",
              attr(x, "display", exact = TRUE)[i +
                                                 1]
            ),
            digits = abs(attr(x, "digits",
                              exact = TRUE)[i + 1])
          ),
          format.args)
          cols[, i + pos] <- do.call("formatC", curFormatArgs)
        }
        else {
          for (j in 1:nrow(cols)) {
            curFormatArgs <- c(list(
              x = xcol[j],
              format = ifelse(
                attr(x,
                     "digits", exact = TRUE)[j, i + 1] <
                  0,
                "E",
                attr(x, "display", exact = TRUE)[i +
                                                   1]
              ),
              digits = abs(attr(x, "digits",
                                exact = TRUE)[j, i + 1])
            ),
            format.args)
            cols[j, i + pos] <- do.call("formatC",
                                        curFormatArgs)
          }
        }
      }
      if (any(ina))
        cols[ina, i + pos] <- NA.string
      if (is.numeric.column) {
        cols[, i + pos] <- sanitize.numbers(
          cols[, i + pos],
          type = type,
          math.style.negative = math.style.negative,
          math.style.exponents = math.style.exponents
        )
      }
      else {
        if (is.null(sanitize.text.function)) {
          cols[, i + pos] <- sanitize(cols[, i + pos],
                                      type = type)
        }
        else {
          cols[, i + pos] <- sanitize.text.function(cols[,
                                                         i + pos])
        }
      }
    }
    multiplier <- 5
    full <- matrix("", nrow = nrow(x), ncol = multiplier *
                     (ncol(x) + pos) + 2)
    full[, 1] <- BROW
    full[, multiplier * (0:(ncol(x) + pos - 1)) + 2] <- BTD1
    full[, multiplier * (0:(ncol(x) + pos - 1)) + 3] <- BTD2
    full[, multiplier * (0:(ncol(x) + pos - 1)) + 4] <- BTD3
    full[, multiplier * (0:(ncol(x) + pos - 1)) + 5] <- cols
    full[, multiplier * (0:(ncol(x) + pos - 1)) + 6] <- ETD
    full[, multiplier * (ncol(x) + pos) + 2] <-
      paste(EROW, lastcol[-(1:2)],
            sep = " ")
    if (type == "latex")
      full[, 2] <- ""
    result <- result + lastcol[2] + paste(t(full), collapse = "")
    if (!only.contents) {
      if (tabular.environment == "longtable") {
        if (!booktabs) {
          result <- result + PHEADER
        }
        if (caption.placement == "bottom") {
          if ((!is.null(caption)) && (type == "latex")) {
            result <- result + BCAPTION + xtable:::as.string(caption) +
              ECAPTION
          }
        }
        if (!is.null(attr(x, "label", exact = TRUE))) {
          result <- result + BLABEL + attr(x, "label",
                                           exact = TRUE) + ELABEL
        }
        ETABULAR <- "\\end{longtable}\n"
      }
      result <- result + ETABULAR
      result <- result + ESIZE
      if (floating == TRUE) {
        if ((!is.null(caption)) && (type == "latex" &&
                                    caption.placement == "bottom")) {
          result <- result + BCAPTION + xtable:::as.string(caption) +
            ECAPTION
        }
        if (!is.null(attr(x, "label", exact = TRUE)) &&
            caption.placement == "bottom") {
          result <- result + BLABEL + attr(x, "label",
                                           exact = TRUE) + ELABEL
        }
      }
      result <- result + EENVIRONMENT
      if (!is.null(extra))
        result <- result + paste0(extra, "\n")
      result <- result + ETABLE
    }
    result <- sanitize.final(result, type = type)
    if (print.results) {
      xtable:::print.string(result)
    }
    return(invisible(result$text))
  }

'+.string' <- function (x, y) {
    x$text <- paste(x$text, xtable:::as.string(y)$text, sep = "")
    return(x)
}
```

You can use `myprint.xtable` as follows.

```
myprint.xtable(table1, extra="\\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Title of Table}")
```

The result is:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  \hline
1 & 4 & 4 \\ 
  2 & 4 & 4 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Nice table} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Title of Table}
\end{table}
```